# Failed to add interface to sandbox

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm trying to run two Docker containers attached to a single Docker network using Docker Compose.
I'm running into the following error when I run the containers:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to add interface veth5b3bcc5 to sandbox: 
error setting interface "veth5b3bcc5" IP to 172.19.0.2/16: 
cannot program address 172.19.0.2/16 in sandbox 
interface because it conflicts with existing 
route {Ifindex: 10 Dst: 172.19.0.0/16 Src: 172.19.0.1 Gw: <nil> Flags: [] Table: 254}
```

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  dsn-redis-data:
    driver: local

  dsn-redis-conf:
    driver: local

networks:
  dsn-net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  duty-students-notifier:
    image: duty-students-notifier:latest
    network_mode: host
    container_name: duty-students-notifier
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    env_file: ../.env
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    networks:
      - dsn-net
    restart: always

  dsn-redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - dsn-redis-data:/var/lib/redis
      - dsn-redis-conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    networks:
      - dsn-net
    restart: always
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does your host network environment have another interface with a 172.19.0.0/16 network?  You have a somewhat odd combination of network settings – `networks: [...]` and `network_mode: host` conflict – does it help to remove absolutely all of the network-related settings from the file?

Comment: Oh, I see now. Forgot to remove `network_mode: host` from the config. Now everything works perfectly. Thanks for pointing me out. You can post the answer if you wish. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `network_mode: host` setting generally disables Docker networking, and can interfere with other options.  In your case it looks like it might be trying to apply the `networks:` configuration to the host system network layer.

`network_mode: host` is almost never necessary, and deleting it may resolve this issue.